# Any way to access Gearman administration?

Tags: php, gearman

I want to be able to query a gearman server to determine how many instances of a worker I have running (basically I want to make sure that `RunTaskA` is available and `RunTaskB` is available if there are no workers handling those tasks, I want to be able to send an alert out.

Is there any way to do this?

Also: Mad props if you know of a PHP way to query the gearman server.

**Edit**: I know about the PHP gearman extension that is available natively, but I am not looking for a task submission extension, I need something that allows me to query the gearman server and see how many workers are serving a specific task.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

```
class Waps_Gearman_Server {

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    protected $host = "127.0.0.1";
    /**
     * @var int
     */
    protected $port = 4730;

    /**
     * @param string $host
     * @param int $port
     */
    public function __construct($host=null,$port=null){
        if( !is_null($host) ){
            $this->host = $host;
        }
        if( !is_null($port) ){
            $this->port = $port;
        }
    }

    /**
     * @return array | null
     */
    public function getStatus(){
        $status = null;
        $handle = fsockopen($this->host,$this->port,$errorNumber,$errorString,30);
        if($handle!=null){
            fwrite($handle,"status\n");
            while (!feof($handle)) {
                $line = fgets($handle, 4096);
                if( $line==".\n"){
                    break;
                }
                if( preg_match("~^(.*)[ \t](\d+)[ \t](\d+)[ \t](\d+)~",$line,$matches) ){
                    $function = $matches[1];
                    $status['operations'][$function] = array(
                        'function' => $function,
                        'total' => $matches[2],
                        'running' => $matches[3],
                        'connectedWorkers' => $matches[4],
                    );
                }
            }
            fwrite($handle,"workers\n");
            while (!feof($handle)) {
                $line = fgets($handle, 4096);
                if( $line==".\n"){
                    break;
                }
                // FD IP-ADDRESS CLIENT-ID : FUNCTION
                if( preg_match("~^(\d+)[ \t](.*?)[ \t](.*?) : ?(.*)~",$line,$matches) ){
                    $fd = $matches[1];
                    $status['connections'][$fd] = array(
                        'fd' => $fd,
                        'ip' => $matches[2],
                        'id' => $matches[3],
                        'function' => $matches[4],
                    );
                }
            }
            fclose($handle);
        }

        return $status;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 25):

For quick checking, I use this bash one-liner:

```
# (echo status ; sleep 0.1) | netcat 127.0.0.1 4730
```

This opens a connection to a gearman instance running on localhost, and sends the "status" query. This contains the name and number of jobs on that instance. The information can then be processed with grep/awk/wc etc. for reporting and alerting.

I also do the same with the "workers" query which shows all connected workers.

```
# (echo workers ; sleep 0.1) | netcat 127.0.0.1 4730
```

The sleep is to keep the connection open long enough for the reply.

The full list of administrative commands, and what the output means is at http://gearman.org/index.php?id=protocol Just search for "Administrative Protocol"

Comment: Very nice, I like how simple this solution is.

Answer (score 4):

To expand on d5ve's answer, since netcat will sit and wait on the socket, you can add a -w parameter with a maximum number of seconds to run. So if you're querying localhost:

```
# (echo status ; sleep 0.1) | netcat 127.0.0.1 4730 -w 1
```

... otherwise you never get back to a command prompt.

Answer (score 1):

As far as i know there are no such extension in gearman, Managing and monitoring worker script is your responsibility you can try one of these for this purpose -

Supervisord is a python appliation for running application in background and monitoring them.

OR you can use brian moon's [gearman manager](http://github.com/brianlmoon/GearmanManager)

Comment: I guess I'll have to devise some sort of heartbeat system.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need this
http://github.com/liorbk/php

Answer (score 0):

[Gearman has a php extension](http://gearman.org/index.php?id=php_reference). Have you looked into that yet?

[PHP Link](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/book.gearman.php)

Comment: That is for submitting tasks. I am already using that, that extension does not provide any access to the administrative side of gearman

Answer (score 0):

Stumbled on it today, haven't tested it myself but it looks promising.

https://github.com/yugene/Gearman-Monitor

Answer (score 0):

In Python you could do the following:

```
import gearman

admin_client = gearman.GearmanAdminClient(['127.0.0.1:4730',])
status = admin_client.get_status()
for w in status:
   if w["task"] == "YOUR_TASK_NAME":
      print(w)
```

**Note**: you have to install package named "gearman" using pip or easy_install to avoid any exceptions running the above code.

Also, Check the following admin clients that is simplifying administering gearman in general.

- [Monitoring and Administerating Gearman servers easily from a Django based interface](https://github.com/muhammadsa/Django-GearmanAdmin)
- [Monitoring tool for Gearman servers](https://github.com/yugene/Gearman-Monitor)
- [PHP daemon for managing gearman workers](https://github.com/brianlmoon/GearmanManager)
- [PHP monitoring dashboard for Gearman Job Servers](https://github.com/gaspaio/gearmanui)
- [http server that sits on top of gearman](https://github.com/Clever/gearman-admin)

Answer (score 0):

When everything else fails, you can use the `gearadmin` tool found in the `gearman-tools` package in Ubuntu by calling `exec()` to execute it in the new process. Here is [a reference to its output format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20750896/gearman-gearadmin-command-line-tool-status-output-meaning).

This assumes PHP and Gearman are running on the same server.