# Gearman gearadmin command line tool status output meaning

Tags: php, gearman

I am unable to find any documentation on the meaning of the gearadmin command line tool with the '--status' option. What is the meaning of the three numbers found after the worker function name ?

For example, then I run this command:

```
gearadmin --status
```

I get the following output:

```
worker-function-name    114 0   0
.
```

I don't know the meaning of the three numbers after the 'worker-function-name'. I don't think it matters but I'm using gearman with the php extension and ubuntu 13.10 server.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

- Function Name
- Number in queue
- Number of jobs running
- Number of capable workers

https://preilly.me/monitoring-gearman-over-telnet-port-4730/

Comment: thanks its funny they haven't mention this in their doc

Comment: Last 0 shows worker is not running and If show 1 then It means It is running. So in case of 0 you need to restart worker. then It will process queues

Answer (score 11):

Since this is the only question related to output of command `gearadmin --status`, allow me to share a quick tip for pretty printing the output of this command.

```
gearadmin  --status | sort -n | column -t
```

This becomes useful when you have a lot of different workers and their relative counts matter. I always have one tab of my terminal where I run the following command to watch queue length and worker count go up and down in realtime. Well, realtime enough.

```
watch "gearadmin  --status | sort -n | column -t"
```